# There are duplicated rewrites for: Blocks: adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_super_config

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, overrides

I have just started using PHPStorm and had installed the Magento module on it. When I open my project now I get an error that `There are duplicated rewrites for: Blocks: adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_super_config`

Looking in the code I think this is because two extensions I use, CJM Swatches and QS Quick Configurables both in their config.xml reference :

**CJM:**

```
<adminhtml>
 <rewrite>
  <catalog_product_edit_tab_super_config>CJM_ColorSelectorPlus_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Super_Config</catalog_product_edit_tab_super_config>
 </rewrite>
</adminhtml>
```

**QS Quick Configurables**

```
<adminhtml>
 <rewrite>
  <catalog_product_edit_tab_super_config>QS_Quickconfigurables_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Super_Config</catalog_product_edit_tab_super_config>
 </rewrite>
</adminhtml>
```

Not having the greatest understanding of the inner workings of Magento I am a bit stuck how to fix this, I thought maybe deleting the QS rewrite rule, then in the relevant Config.php change

```
class QS_Quickconfigurables_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Super_Config extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Super_Config implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
```

to

```
class QS_Quickconfigurables_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Super_Config extends CJM_ColorSelectorPlus_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Super_Config implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
```

But have no idea if this is the right thing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is, do they overwrite the same behaviour (aka method), if yes, you have a problem. If not you can just extend the one class from the other and everything is fine.

The problem here is, that you change a module you shouldn't change, but I don't see an alternative at the moment.

## They overwrite the same method

If they overwrite the same method, you have to check what they do and copy the code together. I recommend to have your own module, add a dependency to both modules (so your config is loaded after the other two) then you can add a rewrite for the block with your own block and insert there the code you copy.

Comment: In the code they overwrite different functions, however in the __construct they both set a different $this->setTemplate

Comment: then you have a real problem, because you have to merge the templates too.

Comment: Oh Joy! Time to diff them :)